# webrtc broadcast from headless RPi

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

How to stream audio and video using webrtc from headless (no web browser) RPi?
There are examples on uv4l RPi, but they don't work on iOS.
My question is about nodejs and webrtc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following libraries:

- https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc
- https://github.com/pion/webrtc
- https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc

Here is an example application, that streams video using ffmpeg to web page:
https://github.com/ashellunts/ffmpeg-to-webrtc

Comment: Checking the first link, nice, but still needs a web browser for a server (broadcaster). I would like to implement it on a headless RPi (no GUI, no web browser). Web browser on client (observer) side only.

Comment: There is no meed in browser on server.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Maybe I am missing something?Can you be more descriptive? Maybe I am missing something? I am following the instructions from here https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/blob/master/README.md . Usage Install the project's dependencies and run the tests before starting the application server: npm install npm test npm start Then, navigate to http://localhost:3000.  After that I a broadcaster and viewer

Comment: Using node-webrtc you can connect to other WebRTC agent, e.g. browser and stream media.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still don't know how to do it. Can you kindly describe briefly the process or provide link to more info/tutorial/example how to do it. I'm still in a dark

Comment: If you share what you have tried and what did not work, what problem you have encountered. Then I can better help you.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/play-from-disk)

Comment: The last example application https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/play-from-disk is a playback from file, not a live stream.  I'm having a look at https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples and all examples use a local nodejs server. Can you point me to a single example with a web server?

Comment: Here is example that streams video using ffmpeg
https://github.com/ashellunts/ffmpeg-to-webrtc

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, appreciate it. I will have a look at the example, however it uses ffmpeg and I need H. 264 . I will search and study more.

Comment: You are welcome. Right, it uses ffmpeg, also it uses H.264 together with ffmpeg. I am pretty sure that is what you need. You need to find how to record video from RPi using ffmpeg. After that you will need to pass same ffmpeg arguments to the ffmpeg-to-webrtc application. And as a result you will have video streamed to web page. Ffmpeg-to-webrtc is my project. Don't hesitate to ask questions if it is still not clear. You can also open issue in ffmpeg-to-webrtc GitHub page, we can continue discussion there.